# Looping through connect four grid

Tags: java

I am working on a Connect Four project, but am struggling with the win check. I think it has something to do with how I am looping over the grid. It works horizontally but not vertically, and it kinda works diagonally.

```
public boolean gameStatus(MyBoard gameBoard, int columnPosition, CellState gameToken) {
    int rowPosition = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.getWidth(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < gameBoard.getHeight(); j++)
            if (gameBoard.get(i, columnPosition) != CellState.FREE)
                rowPosition = i;

    if (checkColumn(gameBoard, columnPosition, gameToken, rowPosition))
        return true;
}


public boolean checkColumn(MyBoard gameBoard, int columnPosition, CellState gameToken, int rowPosition) {
    int tokenCounter = 1;

    if ((rowPosition + 4) <= 6)
        for (int i = rowPosition + 1; i <= rowPosition + 3; i++)
            if (gameToken == gameBoard.get(i, columnPosition))
                tokenCounter++;
            else
                break;

    if (tokenCounter == 4)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is your `if (checkColumn(...))` statement supposed to execute as part of your `for` loop? Your indentation suggests that that might be your intention, but as it stands it won't.

Answer (score 2):

I think this only checks the last row which is non-empty.

Java doesn't care about indentation, so without braces, `if` and `for` only use the statement after them. This means your `if (checkColumn...` only runs once, not once for each column.

You might want to try something like

```
public boolean gameStatus(MyBoard gameBoard, int columnPosition, CellState gameToken) { 
    int rowPosition = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gameBoard.getHeight(); j++) {
            if (gameBoard.get(i, columnPosition) != CellState.FREE) {
                rowPosition = i;
            }
        }
        if (checkColumn(gameBoard, columnPosition, gameToken, rowPosition)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

In general. I'd advise against writing `if`, `for` and `while` statements without braces. The two characters it saves is not worth the bugs you may accidentally introduce

Comment: Thank you, now it works horizontally. You are right, it's not worth it given how I have spent several hours with this problem and the error was a simple bracket mistake.